# Using infinitive instead of gerund?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Are these sentences have a difference with meaning, tense or etc. between each other:

- Playing is easy.
- To play is easy.

and

- They need getting up early.
- They need to get up early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little or no difference in the meaning of the gerund and the "to"-infinitive.

Some words *require* one or the other.

*Need* normally requires a "to"-infinitive, so *They need to get up early*. In this it is like *want* and *ought*.

As it happens, *need* has a second, different, construction with the gerund. It is rather colloquial, and it has a passive sense. So *They need getting up early* means *Somebody should get them up early*. It cannot mean the same as *They need to get up early*. This is a special feature of *need*, and is not necessarily shared by other words.

In fact, in this sense, it is about the speaker's need, not the subject's. When the subject is inanimate (eg *This salad needs washing*) this does not make much difference, but when it is people, as in your example, the implication of *They need getting up early* is something like *Somebody should get them up early, whether they want to get up early or not!*

Comment: Thanks for your answer I didn't understand a point. Which one is passive voice and how? And what about my "play" example? Is it same and have a passive voice?

Comment: @user123960: In the normal use of _need_, with an infinitive, the infinitive is active: in _They need to get up_ it is they who have the need, and they who get up. In _I need them to get up_, I have the need, but they do the getting up. In the colloquial _They need getting up_, it is the speaker who has the need, and getting up is something that is done to them: somebody is to make them get up - that's what I mean by "passive". In the case ofyour _play_ example, both are grammatical, and there is little difference in meaning. _Playing is easy_ is more idiomatic.